# discover route path in service handler

Tags: servicestack

Using ServiceStack 3.9.2x.

Routes paths are defined by decorating DTOs with a Route attribute.

Is there a way (other than by reflection) to find out what what the route path is in the service handler? When I say service handler I mean the (Get, Put, Post, etc.) method that takes the request DTO and services the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the implementation of the `IReturn<T>.ToUrl()` [extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/UrlExtensions.cs) which does exactly that, uses the custom routes if defined otherwise returns the pre-defined url.

#### Usage:

```
[Route("/custom/route")]
public class RequestDto : IReturn<ResponseDto> { ... }

var relativeUrl = new RequestDto { ... }.ToUrl("GET", "json");
```